# Any thing that is similar to the amazon s3 to store images from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page where i store images for each post and i store images in files using paperclip but i want to store it in the amazon s3 instead of storing it in folder. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain it.

1. add `gem 'aws-sdk'` to you gemfile. (don't forget to bundle install)
2. create a new file in `{APP FOLDER}/config/s3.yml` with the following content:
   access_key_id: xxxxxYOUR_ACCESS_KEY_IDxxxxx
   enter code heresecret_access_key: xxxxxYOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEYxxxxx
3. Update your model accordingly:

   ```
                 has_attached_file :file_field_name,
                 :storage => :s3,
                 :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                 :url => '/path/tofile/:basename.:extension',
                 :path => '/path/tofile/:basename.:extension',
                 :bucket => 'YOUR_BUCKET'
   ```
4. At last in your views:

   ```
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :logo, "file_field_name" %>
     <%= f.file_field :file_field_name %>
   </div>
   ```

Any issues let me know.

As for the alternatives to S3, Windows Azure Storage and Nimbus.io.

Comment: I have the access_key_id and secret_access_key but what do i have to specify in bucket?

Comment: The name of the bucket you created on S3. You can do it from the AWS Web console.

Comment: No, I have not created bucket. I just created an account.

Comment: Then you need to log in into your account aws.amazon.com, then look for AWS Management Console. Look for S3 and create a bucket. And you are good to go. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Ok. I have seen it and i did not actually finished creating my account  because i have not provided the payment details. I tried creating free tier but still it is asking for payment details. why?

Comment: Apparently they need your credit card info even if its free tier. You will not be charged if you stay under the free tier limits.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15948/discussion-between-usr-and-luis-d-urraca)

Comment: I tried PaperClipExample and it is working fine. I use s3 to store images. And i want to know how the images are displayed. To say exactly, i have

pic_file_name,
pic_content_type,
pic_file_size,
pic_updated_at 
in the user model. I do not have url of the pic, then how can i able to get the images using

<%= image_tag @user.pic.url %>

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly thorough documentation about it [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3), take a look.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://dchua.com/2012/04/25/update-amazon-s3-paperclip-and-a-curious-case-of-singapore-buckets/) is a minimal howto.

For testing and development you can use fake-s3

Descrtiption from [github page](https://github.com/jubos/fake-s3):
"FakeS3 is a lightweight server that responds to the same calls Amazon S3 responds to.
It is extremely useful for testing of S3 in a sandbox environment without actually making calls to Amazon, which not only require network, but also cost you precious dollars."

I think you should stay with Amazon S3 in production. I do not know a better alernative. It works.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding in Amazon S3 there is nothing called folders to store the data. we have used  S3 for string images only but it was stored in the virtual folder S3 termed it as bucket, there are C# API available to read those virtual folders( buckets) information to access the data. there is also AWS SDK available for C#.